# Conditionals in CSS object

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Since [May 2018](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/1732), we can write CSS objects in styled components.

Is it possible though to have conditionals in the objects (as we can with "normal" styled components). I cannot get the following conditional to work:

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button({
  backgroundColor: colors.defaultBlue,
  borderRadius: '20px',
  color: props => (props.hover === true ? '#fff' : '#000'),
  border: 'none'
})
```

Comment: Did you try `props => (this.props.hover ? '#fff' : '#000')`. Or evaluate outside the object and pass the result in?

Comment: Presumably you'd need to define this as a function, which takes `props` and returns `styled.button`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
const StyledButton = styled.button((props) => ({
  backgroundColor: colors.defaultBlue,
  borderRadius: '20px',
  color: props.hover === true ? '#fff' : '#000',
  border: 'none'
}))
```